# Scatterplot displaying line (y axis is not in order)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some simple data on a graph without numpy arrays and I'm having an issue where the Y axis is not in order so it's showing it as a line. Picture below.
[image]

Also if anyone knows how I can change the scaling/remove ticks from my x/y, say I want every 10 years starting from 1970 to 2010 rather than every single point.

This is how my data is laid out and how I print it:

```
x = [1973, 1974, 1975, ...]
y = [5000, 8000, 9000, ...]

matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: If your data really looked like you say, this problem would not occur. In reality your data are strings, not numbers, i.e. `x = ["1973", "1974", "1975", ...]` and you will need to convert them to numbers first, `x = [int(i) for i in x]`, or `x = list(map(int, x))`.

Comment: I appreciate it, I was reading the values in from a file and didn't even think about that being a problem, if you wanna post that as the answer i'll mark it.